# Continuity of product maps

Tags: general-topology, continuity, product-space

Let $J$ be a given (countably or uncountably infinite) index set. Let $\{\  X_\alpha \ \colon \ \alpha \in J \ \}$ and $\{\  Y_\alpha \ \colon \ \alpha \in J \ \}$ be collections of topological spaces.

Let the sets $X$ and $Y$ be given by 
$$X \colon= \Pi_{\alpha \in J} X_\alpha, $$
and 
$$Y \colon= \Pi_{\alpha \in J} Y_\alpha, $$
respectively.

For each $\alpha \in J$, let $f_\alpha \colon X_\alpha \to Y_\alpha$ be a continuous map.

Let $f \colon X \to Y$ be defined by 
$$f\left( (x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in J} \right) \colon= \left( f_\alpha(x_\alpha) \right)_{\alpha \in J} \ \ \ \mbox{ for } \ (x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in J} \in X.$$

Then is $f$ continuous if

(i) both $X$ and $Y$ are given the product topologies?

(ii) $X$ is given the product topology and $Y$ is given the box topology?

(iii) $X$ is given the box topology and $Y$ is given the product topology?

(iv) both $X$ and $Y$ are given the box topologyies?

If  $J$ is finite, then (i), (ii), (iii), and (iv) reduce to just one case and then  $f$ is continuous. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i) Yes. This is well-known fact, which holds because a map $f:Z\to\prod Y_\alpha$  is continuous iff each composition map $\pi_\beta\circ f$ is continuous, where $\pi_\beta: \prod Y_\alpha\to  Y_\beta$ is the projection onto $\beta$-th factor.

(ii)    No. For a counterexample it suffices to put as $J$ an arbirary infinite set, $X_\alpha=Y_\alpha$  for each $\alpha\in J$  and $f:X_\alpha\to Y_\alpha$ be the identity map. If the box topology on $\prod Y_\alpha$ does not coincide with the product topology, we shall have a counterexmple.

(iii)   Yes. This follows from (i), because the box topology on $X$ is stronger than the product topology.

(iv)    Yes. If follows since the inverse image of an element of a canonical base of the space $Y$ is open in the space $X$.

Comment: thank you so much. Yes, I've gotten your answer, but I think you might wana edit your answer for a couple of mistakes or typos.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: is it possible for the product topology and the box topology to coincide if the index set is infinite?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud It seems that the coincidence holds iff all but finitely many factors have antidiscrete topology.